# How to open a custom sized firefox window when open in tabs is set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

As a javascript learning experience with a real world use I am trying to write an app that will popup a 600x400 window with a list of userids and passwords. The problem is I have firefox set to display new windows in tabs and I don't want to change that setting. Things I have tried:

1. I have apache installed on my desktop so I tried just creating a web page with what I need but of course it just opens in a tab.  I can't find anyway to white-list a page to open in a new window.
2. I tried a bookmarklet that uses the jquery ui dialog.

`<a href="javascript:(function()document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='/passwords/passwords_test.js';})();">Test load js</a>`

This code works for localhost opened pages but not for pages from the web.  The path to my js file seems to get appended to the pages url and then firebug shows a 404 could not find page error.  If I could figure out why this is happening maybe I could get it to work.

1. I tried using the bash terminal.  $ firefox -new-window -width 600 -height 400.  That opened firefox in a new window but it was the same size as the firefox window I had opened.  Googling revealed that ignoring the -width & -height parameters is an old bug.  The work around was to do $ firefox -no-remote -new-window "www.cnn.com" -width 600 -height 400. That works but only if firefox is not running.  If firefox is running you get an error saying firefox is not responding and you must shutdown that instance of firefox or restart your computer.

So I'm stuck, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Ultimately you can't rely on being able to force client browsers to do things like that. Not all browsers are the same, but in general this is something completely under user control.

Comment: Try to use `showModalDialog()` to show your pop-up. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.showModalDialog

Comment: @Teemu, unfortunately showModalDialog() defeats the purpose of the app, ie viewing the info while typing it in the web page, but it lead me to discover openDialog.  I tried openDialog but that gave a security error.  Googling the error led to a couple of possible solutions, but they are very complex and will take me awhile to figure them out.  Thanks for giving me the info to keep pursuing this.